# How to set up database connection in r2dbc?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

How to set up a PostgreSQL database connection in r2dbc Spring boot project?

I have tried the below configuration, it connects to the database but it's not returning any values

```
@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcRepositories
public class DatabaseConfig extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {

    @Override
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return ConnectionFactories.get("r2dbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sample");
    }

    /*@Override
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return ConnectionFactories.get(new PostgresqlConnectionFactory(
                PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .host("localhost")
                .port(5432)
                .username("postgres")
                .password("thirumal")
                .database("sample")
                .build()););
    }*/

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sample
spring.r2dbc.username=postgres
spring.r2dbc.password=thirumal
spring.r2dbc.pool.enabled=true
```

Model

```
@Data@NoArgsConstructor@AllArgsConstructor@Getter@Setter
@ToString
@Table("public.test")
public class Test implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4205798689305488147L;

    @Id//@Column("id")
    private Long id;
    
    private String name;
    
}
```

Repository

```
public interface TestRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Test, Long> {

}
```

REST CONTROLLER:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public Mono<Test> test() {
   testRepository.findById(3L).subscribe(v->System.out.println("Value: " + v.toString()));
   return testRepository.findById(3L);
}
```

It prints the output in the console but in the JSON, I get only empty braces `{}`

What is the correct way to configure? Any other configuration is required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem. It's `Lombok` library, I didn't install it in eclipse.

When I created the `getter` and `setter` method manually it worked.

```
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Then, I set up the `lombok` and used `@getter` and `@setter` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This configuration works for me, but I use the `DatabaseClient` instead of the `R2dbcRepositories` to query the data:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfiguration extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {

        return new PostgresqlConnectionFactory(PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .host("localhost")
                .port(5432)
                .username("username")
                .password("password")
                .database("mydb")
                .build());
    }

}
```

Then in the repository:

```
@Repository
public class MyRepository {

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseClient client;


    public Flux<String> getString() {
        ....
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

If it's connect to the database probably your configuration is right, can you share also the code used to get the data?

It's possible that you are getting the result as `Mono` or `Flux`, but not reading from it (try with `subscribe()`).

```
Mono<String> mono = db.getData();
mono.subscribe(value -> System.out.println(value));
```

Comment: Correct, there is no problem in the database connection. It prints the output in the code but in the JSON it's just `{}`

Comment: I found the problem, missed `Getter & Setter`.